# How to run a Java EE Web Application outside Netbeans with GlassFish

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, netbeans, glassfish

How to run a Java EE Web Application outside Netbeans?

I've got a Java EE Web Application deployed in GlassFish.
It runs well when launched from Netbeans, but when trying to launch the application outside Netbeans from the GlassFish Admin Console, GlassFish shows a 404 error in the web browser with this description: The requested resource () is not available.

I cleaned and build it in Netbeans and redeployed it again. Closed Netbeans and started the GlassFish server again from Commandline and tried to launch it again from GlassFish Admin Console but it will still show a 404 error. In the server log it doesn't show any error. There's also another web application in GlassFish and that one does launch. The only difference is that I'm using PrimeFaces in the one that fails.

Comment: How do you start your web app from the command line? Are you aware that this step is not necessary if the app has already been deployed from NetBeans?

Comment: @perissf No, I'm starting it from GlassFish Admin Console where there is a button named launch and also I know it's deployed from NetBeans but it gives the same error when typing in the direct url into a web browser.

Comment: @vkraemer I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: deploy the app from the console, that will download a JNLP file.  **then**, launch that JNLP.